Centering a Title within a Bclogo Environment
Consider the code:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\hoffset 10pt \voffset -55pt \oddsidemargin 17pt \evensidemargin 18pt \topmargin 35pt \headheight 25pt \textheight 8.35in \textwidth 5.75in
\headsep 40pt \marginparwidth 35pt

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{RoyalRed}{RGB}{157,16, 45}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
    
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\begin{bclogo}[couleur=RoyalRed!10, epBord=3.5, arrondi=0, logo= ,
barre=none]
{\vspace*{-3pt} \hfil {\color{red} I WOULD LIKE TO CENTER THIS TITLE} \hfil}

\vspace{12pt}

{\large{\textbf{\emph{There is a certain majesty in simplicity.'' \vskip 7pt \hfill ---Alexander Pope \emph{}}}}}
\end{bclogo}
\end{center}
\end{document}

which produces:

QUESTION: How may I center the red title? (I'm not sure why what I have is not working.)
Thank you.

You really want this by using bclogo or some other packages like framed and tcolorbox are acceptable?

@MadyYuvi I need bclogo as the series of documents its come froms contains many of them.

You can achieve the requirement by modifying the command \bcStyleTitre and the MWE is:
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\hoffset 10pt \voffset -55pt \oddsidemargin 17pt \evensidemargin 18pt \topmargin 35pt \headheight 25pt \textheight 8.35in \textwidth 5.75in
\headsep 40pt \marginparwidth 35pt

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{RoyalRed}{RGB}{157,16, 45}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
    
\begin{document}

\renewcommand\bcStyleTitre[1]{\centering #1}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\begin{bclogo}[couleur=RoyalRed!10, epBord=3.5, arrondi=0, logo= ,barre=none]{\color{red}I WOULD LIKE TO CENTER THIS TITLE}

\vspace{12pt}

{\large\textbf{\emph{There is a certain majesty in simplicity.'' \vskip 7pt \hfill ---Alexander Pope \emph{}}}}
\end{bclogo}
\end{center}
\end{document}



Many thanks for this fine answer.
